# How to display deck of cards and compare for doubles

Tags: vb.net

So..  right now I am having a pretty big problem. I have my pictures of a card deck but they are not displaying at all when the deal button is clicked. They were being displayed initially, but I tweaked something and now they are not.. There will be 3 players, this is the test code for player one. Right now it is only set for 16 cards, but you get the idea.

Also, how do I compare to check for doubles and then remove them to a discard pile? Please help, I am beyond my capabilities at this point and I really have no idea how to proceed. Thanks!!

Deckofcardstest

```
Public Class DeckOfCardsTest
    Dim playercards As Integer = 16
    Dim playermatches As Integer
    Dim comp1cards As Integer
    Dim comp1matches As Integer
    Dim comp2cards As Integer
    Dim comp2matches As Integer


    Private deck As New DeckOfCards() ' create the deck of cards


    Private Sub dealButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dealButton.Click
        discard1PictureBox.Visible = True

        deck.Shuffle() ' shuffles the deck

        Dim card1 = deck.DealCard()
        card1PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card1)

        Dim card2 = deck.DealCard()
        card2PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card2)

        Dim card3 = deck.DealCard()
        card3PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card3)

        Dim card4 = deck.DealCard()
        card4PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card4)

        Dim card5 = deck.DealCard()
        card5PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card5)

        Dim card6 = deck.DealCard()
        card6PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card6)

        Dim card7 = deck.DealCard()
        card7PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card7)

        Dim card8 = deck.DealCard()
        card8PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card8)

        Dim card9 = deck.DealCard()
        card9PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card9)

        Dim card10 = deck.DealCard()
        card10PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card10)

        Dim card11 = deck.DealCard()
        card11PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card11)

        Dim card12 = deck.DealCard()
        card12PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card12)

        Dim card13 = deck.DealCard()
        card13PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card13)

        Dim card14 = deck.DealCard()
        card14PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card14)

        Dim card15 = deck.DealCard()
        card15PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card15)

        Dim card16 = deck.DealCard()
        card16PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card16)

        lblPlayerCards.Text = CStr(playercards)




    End Sub ' dealButton_Click

    ' return an image for the Card argument
    Private Function GetCardImage(ByVal card As Card) As Image
        If card IsNot Nothing Then
            ' retrieve specific card image from resources
            Dim pictureResource = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(
              card.ToString().Replace(" ", ""))
            Return CType(pictureResource, Image) ' return Image
        Else
            dealButton.Enabled = False ' disable the Deal Button
            Return Nothing ' no more cards
        End If



    End Function ' GetCardImage

    Private Sub btnQuick_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuick.Click
        discard1PictureBox.Visible = True


        deck.Shuffle() ' shuffles the deck

        Do


            Dim card1 = deck.DealCard()
            card1PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card1)

            Dim card2 = deck.DealCard()
            card2PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card2)

            MessageBox.Show("Thank you for playing")
            dealButton.Enabled = False
            btnQuick.Enabled = False
        Loop
    End Sub


End Class ' DeckOfCardsTest
```

card

```
Public Class Card

    Public Enum CardValue
        Ace = 1
        Two = 2
        Three = 3
        Four = 4
        Five = 5
        Six = 6
        Secen = 7
        Eight = 8
        Nine = 9
        Ten = 10
        Jack = 11
        Queen = 12
        King = 13
    End Enum

    Public Enum CardSuit
        Clubs
        Spades
        Hearts
        Diamonds
    End Enum

    Public Property Value As CardValue
    Public Property Suit As CardSuit

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As CardValue, ByVal suit As CardSuit)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Suit = suit
    End Sub

End Class
```

deckofcards

```
Public Class DeckOfCards
   Private Const NUMBER_OF_CARDS As Integer = 52 ' number of cards
   Private deck(NUMBER_OF_CARDS - 1) As Card ' array of Card objects
   Private currentCard As Integer ' index of next Card to be dealt
   Private Shared randomNumbers As New Random() ' random number generator

   ' constructor fills deck of Cards
   Public Sub New()
      Dim faces() As String = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
         "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}
      Dim suits() As String = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"}
        currentCard = 0 ' set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck(0)



        Dim deck(51) As Card
        Dim cardPosition As Integer = 0

        'loop through each suit and each value in that suit setting one of the deck to that   
        For Each suit As Card.CardSuit In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Card.CardSuit))
            For Each value As Card.CardValue In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Card.CardValue))
                deck(cardPosition) = New Card(value, suit)
                cardPosition += 1
            Next
        Next



   End Sub ' New

   ' shuffle deck of Cards with simple one-pass algorithm
   Public Sub Shuffle()
      ' after shuffling, dealing should start at deck(0) again
      currentCard = 0 ' reinitialize currentCard

      ' for each Card, pick another random Card and swap them
      For first = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
         ' select a random number between 0 and 51
         Dim second As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS)

         ' swap current Card with randomly selected Card
         Dim temp As Card = deck(first) ' store copy of deck(first)
         deck(first) = deck(second) ' move deck(second) to deck(first)
         deck(second) = temp ' move original deck(first) to deck(second)
      Next
   End Sub ' Shuffle

   ' deal one Card
   Public Function DealCard() As Card
      ' determine whether Cards remain to be dealt
      If currentCard <= deck.GetUpperBound(0) Then
         Dim lastCard As Integer = currentCard ' store current card number
         currentCard += 1 ' increment current card number
         Return deck(lastCard)
      Else
         Return Nothing ' no more cards to deal
        End If



    End Function ' DealCard


End Class ' DeckOfCards
```

Comment: There's too much code here to expect us to wade through. Please [edit] your question to only include the code that is actually *relevant* to your question. While you're at it, you can improve your question itself. We have no idea what "not displaying right" means, and you need to clearly describe the problem you're having specifically. We can't see your screen or read your mind from here. :-)

Comment: Nothing is displaying at all. I have the picture boxes set up and the cards are not displaying.

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question and explain it there, not in the comments. You still need to remove the extra code that isn't relevant to your question. Expecting us to wade through an entire wall of code to try and figure out where to even start looking is very inconsiderate of you when you're asking us to give you free help solving your problem. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm sorry, but the problem is I'm a very inexperienced programmer, and I just don't know where the fault is in my programming. I don't have any errors in my code, so I posted the full thing to see where I went wrong.

Comment: If the problem is that your cards are not displaying (which you **still have not edited your question to say** despite being asked twice to do so), then the **relevant** part of your code is the part that should be displaying the cards. I'll ask once again that you [edit] your post (for the third time). If you don't, I'll vote to close it as too localized.

Comment: @KenWhite I was editing when you posted that! I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your `GetCardImage` function, you are using `card.ToString().Replace(" ", "")` to get the name of your card image name from the Resource.

Since you didn't provide how your card images are named in the Resource, I'll will assume they are named as follows:

```
Club1   Spade1   Heart1   Diamond1    --> For Aces of each suit
Club2   Spade2   Heart2   Diamond2    --> For Two's of each suit
.       .        .        .
.       .        .        .
.       .        .        .
Club13  Spade13  Heart13  Diamond13   --> For Kings of each suit
```

In general, each card are named as ***{suitName}{faceValue}***.

Inside your `Card` class, add the following overrides:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
  Dim suit As String = ""

  Select Case Me.Suit
    Case CardSuit.Clubs : suit = "Club"
    Case CardSuit.Diamonds : suit = "Diamond"
    Case CardSuit.Hearts : suit = "Heart"
    Case CardSuit.Spades : suit = "Spade"
  End Select

  Dim value As String = CInt(Me.Value).ToString

  Return suit & value
End Function
```

Inside your `GetCardImage` function, get the name of the card image by using `card.ToString()`, no need to do `Replace()` now since you already formatted the name in the Overrides above.

My code above is solely based on my assumption of how the card images are named in the Resource (ie. as ***{suitName}{faceValue}*** format). If you use different naming format, all you have to do is modify the Overrides function so that it will return the matching card image name for each card suit/values.

Comment: I'm not downvoting (because the answer is well written). However, it's based entirely on information that doesn't exist in the question. I can answer any question on this site by assuming that a condition exists that's not stated in the question; I'd probably be wrong 99.99999% of the time.

Comment: I'm basing on the OP question of why the image not showing. From the code provided by him, he is using card.ToString to get the name of the card image while he is not overriding the ToString method of the class. I might just point that out as a comment instead.